# Detecting reference to cell from other workbooks?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

Is there a way with VBA and/or some formula in Excel to check whether there are other workbooks/sheets referencing a cell? Ideally, also from which workbooks/sheets but if this is not possible, that's also ok.

Lets say I have a workbook with a list of proxy addresses, I want to know if a proxy is already being used by checking if there's any other workbook  referencing its cell. This is to have an indicator whether it's a free proxy or already in use.

Any alternative solution that's close to this is also welcome. I'm not per se looking for a full blown solution, but I can get far by pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Have you looked at Trace Precedents and Trace Dependents in Formula Auditing on the Formulas tab?

Comment: `Range.Dependents` look obvious but it works on the cell's sheet only. You might work with `Range.NavigateArrow`, see this: https://excelhelphq.com/how-to-find-all-dependent-cells-outside-of-worksheet-and-workbook-in-excel-vba/

Comment: Really good question! The Range.Precedents collection does not include cells from other workbooks but LinkSources will give you list to search for.  I have added a full working answer.

Comment: Interesting question. I can think of a few scenarios with false positives (e.g. `=INDEX(A1:A2,2)` would technically never reference `A1`, even though the formula contains `A1`) and false negatives (e.g. `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1))` would always reference `A1`, even though `A1` never appears in the formula). Do these scenarios need to be accounted for here or can they be ignored for your purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is some code, there is some setup code so that you (or other collaborators) can run thru an example of two workbooks, one pointing to another.  Two workbooks get saved to your Temp directory as part of the setup.

For me the output is

```
 Cell at Book2.xlsx!Sheet1!$A$2 has external workbook source of [Book1.xlsx]
```

It works by examining the LinkSources for a workbook and then sweeps through cells looking for that link source.

```
Option Explicit



'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : Investigate
' DateTime  : 06/02/2018 14:40
' Author    : Simon
' Purpose   : Start execution here.  There is some setup code
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Arguments :
'    arg1      : arg1 description
'
Sub Investigate()

    '**************************************************
    ' START of Experiment setup code
    '**************************************************
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook, wb2 As Excel.Workbook

    GetOrCreateMyTwoWorbooks "Book1", "SimonSub1", wb1, "Book2", "SimonSub2", wb2


    wb1.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Formula = "=2^4"


    wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Formula = "=2^2"
    wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("b1").Formula = "=3^2"
    wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("a2").FormulaR1C1 = "=[" & wb1.Name & "]Sheet1!R1C1/r1c1*r1c2"

    '**************************************************
    ' END of Experiment setup code
    '**************************************************

    '**************************************************
    '* now the real logic begins
    '**************************************************

    Dim dicLinkSources As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicLinkSources = LinkSources(wb2)

    '* get all the cells containing formulae in the worksheet we're interested in
    Dim rngFormulaCells As Excel.Range
    Set rngFormulaCells = wb2.Worksheets(1).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)

    '* set up results container (one could report as we find them but I like to collate)
    Dim dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents = New Scripting.Dictionary

    '* loop throught the subset of cells on the worksheet that have formulae
    Dim rngFormulaCellsLoop As Excel.Range
    For Each rngFormulaCellsLoop In rngFormulaCells

        Dim sFormula As String
        sFormula = rngFormulaCellsLoop.Formula  '* I like a copy in my locals window

        '* search for all the link sources (experiment has only one, chance are you'll have many)
        Dim vSearchLoop As Variant
        For Each vSearchLoop In dicLinkSources.Items
            If VBA.InStr(1, sFormula, vSearchLoop, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then

                '* we found one, add to collated results
                dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents.Add wb2.Name & "!" & wb2.Worksheets(1).Name & "!" & rngFormulaCellsLoop.Address, vSearchLoop

            End If
        Next vSearchLoop

    Next

    '*print collated results
    Dim lResultLoop As Long
    For lResultLoop = 0 To dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents.Count - 1
        Debug.Print "Cell at " & dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents.Keys()(lResultLoop) & " has external workbook source of " & dicExternalWorksheetPrecedents.Items()(lResultLoop)

    Next lResultLoop


    Stop
End Sub

'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : LinkSources
' DateTime  : 06/02/2018 14:38
' Author    : Simon
' Purpose   : To acquire list of link sources and more importantly the search term
'             we're going to see to look for external workbooks
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Arguments :
'   [in] wb         : The workbook we want report on
'   [out,retval]    : returns a dictionary with the lik sources in the keys and search term in item
'
Function LinkSources(ByVal wb As Excel.Workbook) As Scripting.Dictionary

    Static fso As Object
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    Dim dicLinkSources As Scripting.Dictionary
    Set dicLinkSources = New Scripting.Dictionary

    Dim vLinks As Variant
    vLinks = wb.LinkSources(XlLink.xlExcelLinks)

    If Not IsEmpty(vLinks) Then
        Dim lIndex As Long
        For lIndex = LBound(vLinks) To UBound(vLinks)

            Dim sSearchTerm As String
            sSearchTerm = ""

            If fso.FileExists(vLinks(lIndex)) Then
                Dim fil As Scripting.file
                Set fil = fso.GetFile(vLinks(lIndex))

                '* this is what we'll search for in the cell formulae
                sSearchTerm = "[" & fil.Name & "]"

            End If

            dicLinkSources.Add vLinks(lIndex), sSearchTerm

        Next lIndex
    End If
    Set LinkSources = dicLinkSources
End Function


'*****************************************************************************************************************
'                                         __                                __
'_____  ______ ___________ ____________ _/  |_ __ __  ______   ______ _____/  |_ __ ________
'\__  \ \____ \\____ \__  \\_  __ \__  \\   __\  |  \/  ___/  /  ___// __ \   __\  |  \____ \
' / __ \|  |_> >  |_> > __ \|  | \// __ \|  | |  |  /\___ \   \___ \\  ___/|  | |  |  /  |_> >
'(____  /   __/|   __(____  /__|  (____  /__| |____//____  > /____  >\___  >__| |____/|   __/
'     \/|__|   |__|       \/           \/                \/       \/     \/           |__|
'
'*****************************************************************************************************************
'* this is just something to setup the experiment, you won't need this hence the big banner  :)
'*
Public Sub GetOrCreateMyTwoWorbooks(ByVal sWbName1 As String, ByVal sSubDirectory1 As String, ByRef pwb1 As Excel.Workbook, _
                                    ByVal sWbName2 As String, ByVal sSubDirectory2 As String, ByRef pwb2 As Excel.Workbook)

    Static fso As Object
    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = VBA.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    On Error Resume Next
    Set pwb1 = Application.Workbooks.Item(sWbName1)
    Set pwb2 = Application.Workbooks.Item(sWbName2)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If pwb1 Is Nothing Then
        Set pwb1 = Application.Workbooks.Add

        Dim sSubDir1 As String
        sSubDir1 = fso.BuildPath(Environ$("tmp"), sSubDirectory1)

        If Not fso.FolderExists(sSubDir1) Then fso.CreateFolder (sSubDir1)

        Dim sSavePath1 As String
        sSavePath1 = fso.BuildPath(sSubDir1, sWbName1)

        pwb1.SaveAs sSavePath1
    End If

    If pwb2 Is Nothing Then
        Set pwb2 = Application.Workbooks.Add

        Dim sSubDir2 As String
        sSubDir2 = fso.BuildPath(Environ$("tmp"), sSubDirectory2)

        If Not fso.FolderExists(sSubDir2) Then fso.CreateFolder (sSubDir2)


        Dim sSavePath2 As String
        sSavePath2 = fso.BuildPath(sSubDir2, sWbName2)

        pwb2.SaveAs sSavePath2
    End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Could you verify the `LinkSources` syntax of  `Set dicLinkSources = LinkSources(wb2)`  in `Sub Investigate`, section "Now the real logic begins" as MS Help states: *expression*`.LinkSources( Type)` where
*expression* should be "a variable that represents a Workbook object." and *Type* a XlLink constant (cf. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/workbook-linksources-method-excel)

Comment: @T.M. : scroll down and you'll see I have defined my own LinkSources routine.  Sorry to have overloaded the term.

Answer (score 2):

On the ribbon > Formulas > Trace precedents > Click:

[image]

It will tell you the following precedent cells:

- cells from current worksheet
- cells from different worksheets
- cells from opened workbooks

If you want to see the percedents of more than 1 cell consider the following:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim myCell  As Range
    For Each myCell In ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        If myCell.HasFormula Then myCell.ShowPrecedents
    Next myCell
End Sub
```

Then you can get something like this:

[image]

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, this only does it for 1 cell at a time. It wouldn't really be an overview if I have to select each cell one by one to check whether it has dependents. Is there a way to show all the dependents (not precedents) at once of the cells in the current sheet?

Comment: OP says _I want to know if a proxy is already being used by checking if there's any other workbook referencing its cell_ so will need `Dependents`, not `Precedents`.  So will need something like `For Each MyCell in RangeOfProxies MyCell.ShowDependents Next`